# How do I replace an actual asterisk character (*) in a Regex expression?

Tags: c#, regex, search, replace

I have a statement:

I have a string such as

```
content = "*   test    *"
```

I want to search and replace it with so when I am done the string contains this:

```
content = "(*)   test    (*)"
```

My code is:

```
content = Regex.Replace(content, "*", "(*)");
```

But this causes an error in C# because it thinks that the * is part of the Regular Expressions Syntax.

How can I modify this code so it changes all asterisks in my string to (*) instead without causing a runtime error?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Since `*` is a regex metacharacter, when you need it as a literal asterisk outside of a character class definition, it needs to be escaped with `\` to `\*`.

In C#, you can write this as `"\\*"` or `@"\*"`.

C# should also have a general purpose "quoting" method so that you can quote an arbitrary string and match it as a literal.

#### See also

- [Regular expressions and escaping special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/regular-expressions-and-escaping-special-characters)

  - Full list of what needs to be escaped, where/when

Answer (score 13):

You can escape it:

`\*`

Comment: Also, consider using a tool if you are composing regular expressions.  Expresso has helped me a lot: http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm

Answer (score 10):

You don't need a regular expression in this simple scenario. You can use String.Replace:

```
content = content.Replace("*", "(*)");
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `\\*` instead of * in regex.replace call

Answer (score 5):

Use `Regex.Escape()` It will take all of the string and make it into something you can use as part of a regex.